# Getting started with motion planning

Tags: ros, motion-planning, gazebo

I have recently finished the [coursera Motion Planning](https://www.coursera.org/learn/robotics-motion-planning/home/welcome) course and I am looking for a project to do, using ROS, OpenRave, Gazebo and similar tools. My project would be in the area of motion planning for a mobile robot. The objective is to take a [turtlebot](http://www.turtlebot.com/) from point A to point B in an environment with dynamic obstacles.

I am looking for suggestions regarding the software architecture and how to connect the above mentioned tools together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're interested in doing generic motion planning the best place to start is with the [MoveIt Project](https://moveit.ros.org/)

If you specifically want to do ground navigation, the ROS [navigation stack](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation?distro=noetic) has been a standard starting point. However if you're getting started now I'd recommend getting involved with [nav2](https://navigation.ros.org/) which is an iteration on the design which is being developed for ROS 2.